# Convert CUnsignedChar pointer to CChar pointer

Tags: ios, swift, unsafe-pointers

I have an objective C function that gives me a

```
UnsafePointer<UInt8>/UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>.
```

However I need this data as a

```
UnsafePointer<Int8>
```

unfortunately the function I require doesn't take

```
UnsafePointer<UInt8>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case an "unsafe bit cast" would be the easiest solution:

```
let ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = ...
let i8ptr = unsafeBitCast(ptr, to: UnsafePointer<Int8>.self)
```

Another option is "memory rebinding":

```
ptr.withMemoryRebound(to: Int8.self, capacity: <count>) { i8ptr in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to produce data loss when parsing the unsigned char to a char?

Comment: @MichaelSchmid: No. You are just re-interpreting an unsigned 8-bit quantity as a signed 8-bit quantity.